# Fill color of individual cells with different color Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I using something like this : I have a global variable for CellStyle 
`CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()` and trying to fill color for all cells from 4th Column.
......

```
    var cell = row.createCell(colIndex)
        if (colIndex == 4) {
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        } else {
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        }

        if (cell != null) {
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
        }
```

by the way I am using HSSFWorkbook and HSSFSheet for reporting.

This way it just fills entire sheet and resulting all cells got filled with LIME color!

Comment: Cell Styles are workbook scoped. Create one at the start for each colour you want

Answer (score 1):

The comment is correct CellStyle is shared and there is a limit for to create new cell styles too.
So I have created three methods for three different styles and one of them: excuse me for the xtend code down.

```
 getCellStyle1(HSSFWorkbook sampleWorkBook) {
        val font = sampleWorkBook.createFont()
        font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL)
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.index)
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.COLOR_NORMAL)

        if (commonCellStyle == null)
            commonCellStyle = sampleWorkBook.createCellStyle()
        commonCellStyle.setCellBorderStyle
        commonCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index)
        commonCellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
        commonCellStyle.setFont(font)
        commonCellStyle.setCellBorderStyle
        return commonCellStyle
    }
```

Similarly I have more getCellStyle2 and getCellStyle3 just create one more if found null so that the styles can be shared across various column.